# How can i extract the information of Trigger in task scheduler by python?

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I want to extract the information of Trigger in task scheduler as shown in the picture below:
[image]

Comment: You can look into win32com: https://dzone.com/articles/create-and-run-scheduled-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get file xml of schedule in path : "C:\windows\system32\Tasks" in Windows 10